# How to go back to the previous page skipping inner page navigation with href="#id". Using javasctip

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

I'm new to javascript and web developments. I'm looking for a way of going back to previous page from current page skipping all the inner page navigation.

I know that back funtionality can be implemented by window.history.back(); or window.history.go(-1);

but this will only send me back to the last inner page navigation, if I have done any.

Example

Let's say I have come from www.firstpage.com and currently I'm in www.secondpage.com. And there are links provided by that page to navigate inside that page. Let's say I have navigate through following path.

www.secondpage.com#id1  --> www.secondpage.com#id2

So my current URL is www.secondpage.com#id2, now I want to go back to www.firstpage.com. Back function will only take me to the www.secondpage.com#id1

Comment: you can always force with window.location.href

Comment: www.firstpage.com is an example there can be multiple ways of coming to www.secondpage.com, so can't use window.location.href. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on internet I realize there is not straight way to do this. So I implemented my own method. When the back option is clicked I called the "goBackContinue" method which continuously call "goBack" in 50mils interval, which call  window.history.back();. So it will back the user continuously till he get out of the page. Following is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="goBackContinue()">Go Back</button>


<script>

function goBackContinue(){
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ goBack() }, 50);

}
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```